# How to calculate Cartesian coordinates for an element after rotation has been applied?

Tags: matrices, geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a square on a  Cartesian coordinate system with `origin (0,0) on top left` (yellow arrow from the picture).

The initial coordinate of the square from the origin are:

```
x          0
y          0
width      100
height     100
boxWidth   100
boxHeight  100
rotation   0
```

Values `boxWidth` and `boxHeight` represent the space between the left margin of the square and the right most margin (included when it is rotated).

After applying a rotation of `45 degree clock wise` with `reference point the center of the square`, I obtain the following values:

```
x         -20.711
y         -20.711
width     100
height    100
boxWidth  141.421
boxHeight 141.421
rotation   45 CW
```

**Question:**

Assuming I know **ONLY** the coordinate for the square rotated (`including boxWidth and boxHeight)` and the value of its rotation in degree.

How to calculate the value of `x, y, boxWidth, boxHeight` after applying rotation of `45 anticlockwise` on already rotated square?

```
x         ???
y         ???
width     100
height    100
boxWidth  ???
boxHeight ???
rotation  0
```

I kindly ask you an explanation on how to possibly solve this problem with a brief sample.
Notes: I wound need to make it working with different rotation values.

[image]

Comment: Please feel free to suggest me a better title if this one is not appropriate or if you need more information please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't understand how a rotation can change the leght of the side of the square.

Comment: @EmilioNovati you are right, my question was confusing, I made an edit I hope it is more clear now. Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a point $(x,y)$, its image $(x',y')$ under a rotationt of angle $\theta$ (in radians) about the origin can be expressed in matrix form as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So if you have a square centred in the origin you can use this to compute the image of each vertex under a rotation (note that a rotation of angle $-\theta$ "undoes" a rotation of angle $\theta$). Further, if the vertices are $(x_1,y_1),\dotsc,(x_4,y_4)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\text{boxWidth} &= \max(x_1,\dotsc,x_4) - \min(x_1,\dotsc,x_4) \\
\text{boxHeight} &= \max(y_1,\dotsc,y_4) - \min(y_1,\dotsc,y_4)
\end{align}
$$
So all you need to do is compute the coordinates of the centre, translate the square so that it is centred in $(0,0)$, apply the rotation as above, and translate it back.

---

The following example assumes that:

1. The coordinate system is fixed.
2. Positive angles correspond to clockwise rotations.
3. When `rotation` is $0$ the sides of the square are parallel to the coordinate axes.
4. $p_{\theta}=(x_{\theta},y_{\theta})$ are the coordinates after a rotation of angle $\theta$ of the vertex which is at the bottom-left when `rotation` is $0$.

Now suppose that, like in your example, the square has sides of length $100$ and is rotated by $\theta = 45°$, i.e. $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians. Then
$$
\begin{align}
R_{\theta} :=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
R_{-\theta} :=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos (-\theta) & -\sin (-\theta) \\
\sin (-\theta) & \cos (-\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Further, observe that if the centre of the square has coordinates $(x_c,y_c)$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{\theta} \\
y_{\theta} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
R_{\theta}
\begin{bmatrix}
-50 \\
-50 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
x_c \\
y_c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
therefore
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_c \\
y_c \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
R_{\theta}
\begin{bmatrix}
50 \\
50 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{\theta} \\
y_{\theta} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we can conclude with
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
y_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
R_{-\theta}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{\theta} - x_c \\
y_{\theta} - y_c \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
x_c \\
y_c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @GibboK It just occurred to me that you might be using a left-handed Cartesian coordinate system, which is very rare in mathematics. Have a look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Ambiguities) on matrix rotations for alternative conventions.